# Wordpress установка WP E-Commerce

Tags: wordpress

Появилась проблема при установке модуля WP E-Commerce на CMS Wordpress, проблема заключается в следующем:
1) Пытаюсь ввести название товара - экран закрашивается темным полупрозрачным цветом и бежит полоска загрузки по центру. 
2) Не возможно загрузить картинку.
Т.е. при загрузке картинки в новый материал - все нормально, а вот при загрузке в товар - после нажатия на кнопку - ничего не происходит.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема и что можно почитать на эту тему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проблема решилась очень просто. Скачал и установил последнюю версию плагина. Вопрос решился.